# How to change the value of a variable in a class [Python]

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I want to add a function that updates the value of the self.ScoreP variable

I have a number on the screen, which prints out the current value of the ScoreP (updateScoreBoard()). It is accurate and works perfectly, but I am also printing out getScoreP. ScoreP prints 0 no matter what the score currently is.

```
            import pygame

            class ScoreBoard():

                def __init__(self):
                    self.WIDTH = 1024
                    self.HEIGHT = 576
                    self.WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
                    self.BLACK = (0,0,0)
                    self.minFont = "font/Minecraft.ttf"
                    self.scoreFont = pygame.font.Font(self.minFont, 75)
                    self.ScoreP = 0
                    self.ScorePStr = str(self.ScoreP)
                    self.ScoreO = 0
                    self.ScoreOStr = str(self.ScoreO)
                    self.ScorePWidth, self.ScorePHeight = self.scoreFont.size(str(self.ScoreP))
                    self.ScoreOWidth, self.ScoreOHeight  = self.scoreFont.size(str(self.ScoreO))
                    self.ScorePX = (self.WIDTH/2)-self.ScorePWidth*2
                    self.ScorePY = 10
                    self.ScoreOX = self.WIDTH/2 + self.ScoreOWidth
                    self.ScoreOY = 10






                def updateScoreBoard(self, screen):
                        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.BLACK, [self.ScorePX, self.ScorePY, self.ScorePWidth, self.ScorePHeight])
                        scorePRender = self.scoreFont.render("{}".format(self.ScoreP), False, self.WHITE)
                        screen.blit(scorePRender, (self.ScorePX,  self.ScorePY))

                        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.BLACK, [self.ScoreOX, self.ScoreOY, self.ScoreOWidth, self.ScoreOHeight])
                        scoreORender = self.scoreFont.render("{}".format(self.ScoreO), False, self.WHITE)
                        screen.blit(scoreORender, (self.ScoreOX,  self.ScoreOY))
                        pygame.display.flip()


                def updateScore(self, playerIncrease, opponentIncrease):
                    self.ScoreP += playerIncrease
                    self.ScorePStr = self.ScoreP

                    self.ScoreO += opponentIncrease 
                    self.ScoreOStr = self.ScoreO


                def getScoreP(self):
                    return self.ScoreP
```

However, the getScore function prints out 0
Even though, the game properly keeps track of and redraws the score

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't see a call to `print`. How/where are you printing it? Please provide the code you're having a problem with. Your indentation is also a bit off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I don't think I changed much, but it works. Also next time give us your whole code including how you test it, because the problem may be there. I added a test at the end that you can delete.

```
import pygame
import random
class ScoreBoard:
    def __init__(self,w,h):
        pygame.font.init()
        self.WIDTH = w
        self.HEIGHT = h
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1024,576))
        self.WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
        self.BLACK = (0,0,0)
        self.minFont = None
        self.scoreFont = pygame.font.Font(self.minFont, 75)
        self.ScoreP = 0
        self.ScoreO = 0
        self.ScorePWidth, self.ScorePHeight = self.scoreFont.size(str(self.ScoreP))
        self.ScoreOWidth, self.ScoreOHeight  = self.scoreFont.size(str(self.ScoreO))
        self.ScorePX = (self.WIDTH/2)-self.ScorePWidth*2
        self.ScorePY = 10
        self.ScoreOX = self.WIDTH/2 + self.ScoreOWidth
        self.ScoreOY = 10
    def updateScoreBoard(self):
        self.ScorePWidth, self.ScorePHeight = self.scoreFont.size(str(int(self.ScoreP)))
        self.ScoreOWidth, self.ScoreOHeight  = self.scoreFont.size(str(int(self.ScoreO)))
        screen = self.screen    
        screen.fill(self.WHITE)

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.BLACK, [self.ScorePX, self.ScorePY, self.ScorePWidth, self.ScorePHeight])
        scorePRender = self.scoreFont.render("{}".format(int(self.ScoreP)), False, self.WHITE)
        screen.blit(scorePRender, (self.ScorePX,  self.ScorePY))

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.BLACK, [self.ScoreOX, self.ScoreOY, self.ScoreOWidth, self.ScoreOHeight])
        scoreORender = self.scoreFont.render(str(int(self.ScoreO)), False, self.WHITE) 
        screen.blit(scoreORender, (self.ScoreOX,  self.ScoreOY))

        pygame.display.flip()       


    def updateScore(self, playerIncrease, opponentIncrease):
        self.ScoreP += playerIncrease
        self.ScoreO += opponentIncrease 


    def getScoreP(self):
        return self.ScoreP
running = True
a = ScoreBoard(1024,576) 
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            break   
    a.updateScore(random.random()/10,random.random()/10)
    a.updateScoreBoard()
```